Solution for typescript errors with mui/material@6.0.0-alpha.0 ? Breaking changes?
I just installed mui/material@6.0.0-alpha.0 in my project because we are very much looking forward to the performance improvements with v6 and I have compile errors but no documented way to fix them. Is sx going away in v6? Any guidance on other breaking changes?
Using DesktopDatePicker with TextField input gives the following type error:
Type '{ onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined; variant: "outlined"; InputProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; ... 293 more ...; hiddenLabel?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<OutlinedTextFieldProps | FilledTextFieldProps | StandardTextFieldProps, "variant">'.
    Types of property 'sx' are incompatible.
      Type 'import(".../node_modules/@mui/system/styleFunctionSx/styleFunctionSx").SxProps<import(".../node_modules/@mui/material/styles/createTheme").Theme> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import(".../node_modules/@mui/system/styleFunctionSx/styleFunctionSx").SxProps<import(".../host/node_modules/@mui/material/styles/createTheme").Theme> | undefined'.
        Type 'SystemCssProperties<Theme>' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.
          Type 'SystemCssProperties<Theme>' is not assignable to type 'CSSSelectorObjectOrCssVariables<Theme>'.
            Property 'position' is incompatible with index signature.
              Type '"relative" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "revert-layer" | "unset" | "-webkit-sticky" | "absolute" | "fixed" | "static" | "sticky" | SystemCssProperties<Theme> | ... 6 more ... | null' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme> | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number | SystemStyleObject<Theme>)'.
                Type 'SystemCssProperties<Theme>' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme> | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number | SystemStyleObject<Theme>)'.ts(23

Here is my code:
    <DesktopDatePicker
                label={translate('start_date')}
                inputFormat={InputFormat}
                value={startDatePicker.date}
                onChange={startDatePicker.handleChange}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />} 
            />

Anywhere we have added sx props to icons to change things like size or rotation, I have a type error:
const warningIconSx: SxProps = { fontSize: '18px' };
<Warning sx={warningIconSx} />{' '}

Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & SvgIconOwnProps & CommonProps & Omit<any, "children" | "classes" | "className" | "sx" | "style" | ... 6 more ... | "titleAccess">): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'SxProps' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.
      Type 'SystemCssProperties<{}>' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.
        Type 'SystemCssProperties<{}>' is not assignable to type 'CSSSelectorObjectOrCssVariables<Theme>'.
          Property 'position' is incompatible with index signature.
            Type '"relative" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "revert-layer" | "unset" | "-webkit-sticky" | "absolute" | "fixed" | "static" | "sticky" | readonly NonNullable<Position | undefined>[] | ... 6 more ... | null' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme> | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number | SystemStyleObject<Theme>)'.
              Type 'readonly NonNullable<Position | undefined>[]' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme> | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number | SystemStyleObject<Theme>)'.
                Type 'readonly NonNullable<Position | undefined>[]' is not assignable to type 'CSSSelectorObjectOrCssVariables<Theme>'.
                  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'readonly NonNullable<Position | undefined>[]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'SxProps' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.

I am not sure how to resolve the DesktopDatePicker issue without further documentation.
I tried changing the type of warningIconSx to this:
const warningIconSx: SxProps<Theme> | undefined = { fontSize: '18px' };
<Warning sx={warningIconSx} />{' '}

And tried importing, one at a time, these different options for Theme but none resolved the type error.
import { Theme } from '@mui/material';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Theme } from '@emotion/react';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles/createTheme';


Asking for a solution is legitimate; asking for documentation as in the title is off-topic.  Suggest you change the title.

Thanks, I know it's in alpha as of last week, so documentation is unlikely.
